# How to output users information with join into table

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I wrote a simple program that has two tables, one `user` and the other `update_acc` where the users table contains the registration details like `username, name, last name, bank, account number` of user while the `update_acc` contains users `username, perfect money name, perfect money no`. I have able to create the join but I want to output it one into a table with each information to its field then it shouldn't bring out every information to the user but just his own information, thanks.

```
` <?php
 require_once 'core/init.php';
error_reporting(0);
require 'db/connect.php';

$sql = "
SELECT 
users.username, users.name, users.last_name, users.bank, update_acc.perfect_money, update_acc.pm_no as update_acc
FROM users
JOIN update_acc ON users.username = update_acc.username
";
$results = $db->query($sql);

if($results->num_rows) {
    while($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
        echo "{$row->username} {$row->name} {$row->last_name} {$row->bank} {$row->update_acc}<br>";
    }
}else{
    echo 'No results.';
}
```

[image: This is basically how I want the table to be like, outputting each information into its field]`

[image: This is the results from my query]

Comment: What is the output u r getting?

Comment: your question is not clear what exactly you need.you already have the user info.what do you mean by `it shouldn't bring out every information to the user but just his own information`.

Comment: The output is the image I attached above with Etimbuk Udoekong Diamond bank

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are looking for is a `where clause`.

```
$sql = "
SELECT 
users.username, users.name, users.last_name, users.bank, update_acc.perfect_money, update_acc.pm_no as update_acc
FROM users
JOIN update_acc ON users.username = update_acc.username
 where users.username='adabebi' ";
```

this will show records for only username `adabebi`

Comment: that's exactly what I need but how do I make it work automatically, like picks a users detail like adabebi once she logs in.

Comment: @Etimbuk if you are using the session you can store it is session to display name(like 'hi adabebi  welcome ') of the user and to use where ever it is required.

Comment: that's part of the issue. But what I need in the actual sense is where a user logs in and can see his transaction history. From what you said, you have a glue to what I need. Something that can grab users id automatically.

Comment: @Etimbuk then at the time of login validate you are getting the username use it get the transaction data.by the way session is meant for this only.